# How to find value after databind to a dropdownlist in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

This is driving me nuts. I have a dropdownlist and I have bound to a sql table.

```
        ddlTypeOntslag.DataTextField = "CodeDesc";
        ddlTypeOntslag.DataValueField = "DTCODE";
        ddlTypeOntslag.DataSource = dal.ListTypeOntslag();
        ddlTypeOntslag.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
        ddlTypeOntslag.DataBind();
```

I can see the values in dropdownlist, but anytime I try to select a value programmatically, either I get error or nothing happens.
I have tried the followings:

```
ddlTypeOntslag.Items.FindByValue("2").Selected = true;
-----------
ListItem selectedListItem = ddlTypeOntslag.Items.FindByValue("2");

                if (selectedListItem != null)
                {
                    selectedListItem.Selected = true;
                    Response.Write("found it");
                }
-----------
ddlTypeOntslag.SelectedIndex = ddlTypeOntslag.Items.IndexOf(ddlTypeOntslag.Items.FindByValue("2"));
```

Nothing seems to work. I have tried with other values, or FindByText, nothing.
Any idea what could be wrong?
PS: I have set the select code after the databind().
PS2: I have set inside the databound event too, but it does not work.

Comment: What you are trying to do exactly? You are selecting the dropdown 3 times whose value is `2`.

Comment: is it so hard to understand it? Why don't you read it carefully where I say: `I have tried the followings`.

Comment: Yes it was, after your edit it's clear now :) Can you tell what is the error you are facing? All the 3 approach should work, please check in your dropdown  if you have any whitespaces in values.

Comment: @IForti : Just before performing this `ddlTypeOntslag.Items.FindByValue("2").Selected = true;`  do add `ddlTypeOntslag.ClearSelection();` Not doing so would obviously cause an error as you can't select two values in one time. See if this work out.